# to compound index or not to compound index (postgres)

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have a page of listings which is loading slowly, I want to check that I have the all right indexes on it.

The table has 5 million rows in it.  Each listing belongs to a channel_id.  The webpage only displays listings for one channel, paginated, so the first 'filter' is always 'channel_id'.  I'll omit the offset and limit for brevity in these examples.

```
select * from listings where channel_id = 5;
```

A listing also has a status column and by default the page opens up on 'active' listings.

```
select * from listings where channel_id = 5 and status = 'active';
```

So we created a compound index on (channel_id, status).

But we also want to filter and have sortable table columns in the UI, on a bunch of other attributes (price, quantity, type, sku, title, has_errors, has_warnings, created_at, updated_at ... etc)

I started with a compound index of all of the attributes together, but that doesn't make much sense since you only sort on one column at a time from the UI.

The postgres docs say: "If one of the types of query is much less common than the others, you'd probably settle for creating just the two indexes that best match the common types"

So it sounds like I should be creating several individual indexes instead of one giant compound index.  My question is: if I know that I'm only dealing with one channel at a time, is it better to create an index just on say 'created_at', or still make compound indexes for each attribute with channel_id in every index eg: (channel_id, created_at) and another for (channel_id, title) and so forth?

Comment: Create an index on "created_at". Run `explain analyze your-query`, edit your question, and paste the output into it. Drop the index on "created_at". Create an index on "(channel_id, created_at)". Clear the cache. Run `explain analyze your-query`, edit your question, and paste the output into it.

Comment: It depends a lot on the selectivity of each index and on whether a composite index might allow the query to benefit from index-only scans. If in doubt, try it and see.

Answer (score 2):

> I'll omit the offset and limit for brevity in these examples.

But you also omitted the `order by` which is relevant for indexing.

> But we also want to filter and have sortable table columns in the UI, on a bunch of other attributes

We can only give particular advice for a particular query.

In this context, the PostgreSQL Doc's quote is applicable: you probably cannot create the indexes for all possible combinations, so chose the most common ones and just take care of them.

So I'd suggest you get the two most common queries with all there `where` and `order by` clauses and add them to your question. Those we can have a look at and give advice.

Alternatively, actually preferably, you start learning about indexing yourself [here](http://use-the-index-luke.com/).

Finally, please be aware that pagination queries are a [special field of optimization](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results) and that `offset` is generally a performance threat better be avoided: See [NoOffset](http://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset) (slides there featuring PostgreSQL benchmarks).

Comment: The order by would be one of 'price', 'quantity', 'sku', 'title', 'listing_type', 'has_errors', 'has_warnings'